# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and Undefined offset errors

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array like this:

```
array (size=2)
  'status' => string 'ok' (length=2)
  'data' => 
    array (size=5)
      'sort_data' => 
        array (size=2)
          'sort_column' => string 'order_item_id' (length=13)
          'sort_order' => string 'asc' (length=3)
```

Now I coded this for getting `sort_column` and it's value and also `sort_order` and it's value:

```
$status = $response['status'];

if($status == 'ok'){
    $nums = count($response['data']['sort_data']); //retrieves 2
    for($i=0; $i<=$nums; $i++){
        foreach($response['data']['sort_data'][$i] as $key=>$value){
            echo $key."=".$value;
        }
    }
}
```

But I get these errors:

**Notice: Undefined offset: 0 on line 6**

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 6**

Line 6:

```
foreach($response['data']['sort_data'][$i] as $key=>$value){
```

So what is going wrong here?

How can I get the contents of `sort_data` within this `foreach` properly?

**UPDATE #1:**

```
Array
(
    [status] => ok
    [data] => Array
        (
            [sort_data] => Array
                (
                    [sort_column] => order_item_id
                    [sort_order] => asc
                )
```

Comment: `for($i=0; $i<=$nums; $i++)` will give you an off by one error. Besides that, the error is telling you exactly the problem. You supply a string value to the foreach.

Comment: @JohnLobo I put this project out of laravel, it is now written in pure PHP

Comment: echo "<pre>"; print_r($response);  exit(); try this

Comment: I added an **update #1**

Comment: @tejoslaeslio can you post expected output as well

Comment: @JohnLobo I need to store each of these into individual variables such as `$sort_column` and `$sort_order`.

Comment: @JohnLobo That's why I decided to use for loop so I could say `for($i=0; $i<=$nums; $i++){
        foreach($response['data']['sort_data'][$i] as $key=>$value){
            $response['data']['sort_data'][$key] = $response['data']['sort_data'][$value];
        }
    }`

Comment: Why are you imploding these paired values with `=`? What is the point?  It looks like mutation for mutation's sake.  XY Problem?  Also, it's all associative keyed, so you can only store a max of one column sorting rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think no need of for loop

```
  if($status == 'ok'){
       
      $sort_column=$response['data']['sort_data']['sort_column'];
      $sort_order=$response['data']['sort_data']['sort_order'];
    }
```

Comment: Then it will give me two results: `sort_column=order_item_id` & `sort_order=asc`. I need to store each of these into indivisual variables such as `$sort_column` and `sort_order`.

Comment: @tejoslaeslio.updated my answer